# Parse request in my simple Node Js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, server

I'm new to Node and am trying to build a simple server in Node using Express. The requests are in the form of say `/input00001/1/output00001`. What I need to do is to parse this request and if the flag is 1 (middle value), I need to replace the file `\home\inputfiles\input00001.txt` with file `\home\outputfiles\output00001.txt`. How is it possible to do that?

Here is my simple server so far. I'm OK with not using the Express and pure NodeJs if that makes things easier.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.send('Hello from Express!');
  request.param
});

app.get('/*', (request, response) => {
  response.send('Start!');
    var url = request.originalUrl;
});

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err);
  }
  console.log(`server is listening on ${port} for incoming messages`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a route that expects these items as url parameters and then use those parameters to do what you want. For example if you're url is `/input00001/1/output00001` then you could set up a route like this:

```
app.get('/:input/:flag/:output', (req, res) => {
    var params = req.params
    var input = params.input   //input0001
    var flag = params.flag     // 1
    var output = params.output //output0001

    // now do what you need to with input, flag, and output
    if(typeof flag!=='undefined' && flag==1){
       var file_name_string = '\home\inputfiles\input00001.txt';
       var res = file_name_string.replace("input", "output");    
     }

    console.log(input, flag, output)
    res.send("done")
})
```

Comment: Thanks! so using the `:` specifies a variable, right? `:input` means put that string in the variable `input`?

Comment: Yes `:input` is a route parameter and it will be available on the `params` object. Lots more here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html under the *express route parameters* heading.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also help with the file copy feature? So I will mark your answer.

Comment: @Ariana I think you should add a separate question about that. It's potentially dangerous to accept url information and use it to access the file system. For example you need to handle situation like `/..%2F..%2FFoo/1/1000` which would translate to a filename `../../Foo` that you might not intend to overwrite. You'll need to sanitize the input, and I'm not sure the best way to do that safely.

Comment: Safety is not important for me at this point. But OK, let me post a separate question.